# Primefaces open closable dialog programmatically

Tags: primefaces, dialog

I want to dynamically create a primefaces dialog from the backing bean.
I have written the code above:

```java
public void showDialog(){
    UIComponent panelGroup = facesContext.getViewRoot().findComponent("form1");
    System.out.println("found or not??"+ panelGroup.toString());
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
    dialog.setId("sample");
    dialog.setWidgetVar("widget");
    dialog.setHeader("Sample");
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    dialog.setMinimizable(true);

    dialog.setDynamic(true);
    dialog.setHideEffect("fade");
    dialog.setFooter("footer");

    dialog.setDraggable(true);
    dialog.setMinWidth(600);
    dialog.setClosable(true);
    dialog.setModal(true);
    dialog.setAppendToBody(false);

    panelGroup.getChildren().add(dialog);

    RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    requestContext.openDialog("widget");
    requestContext.update("form1");
}
```

and in my jsf page: i have

```
 <h:form id="form1" >
        <h:commandButton value="show Dialog" action="#{createDialog.showDialog()}" />

 </h:form>
```

The problem is that when i set it to visible , i got the dialog but neither i can close (i don't get the close icon nor i can drag it)!

Answer (score 5):

You need to replace this line:

```
requestContext.openDialog("widget");
```

to that:

```
requestContext.execute("PF('widget').show()");
```

RequestContext.openDialog() method reffers to Primefaces Dialog Framework API which is different to p:dialog component.

From primefaces user guide:

> Dialog Framework (DF) is used to open an external xhtml page in a
>   dialog that is generated dynamically on runtime.

So, RequestContext.openDialog() expects you to provide path to xhtml page as argument.

And p:dialog component have javascript api show() and hide() methods to interact with it.

Comment: Thank for your answer, it solved the problem and you helped me understand the issue. One more thing i am trying to add content to the dialog from the backing as well, containing html and jsf tags. How it can be possible. Thnx

Comment: You can add jsf child components to dialog the same way you add dialog to form. Link explain how to add html  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301817/programmatically-created-html-components-in-jsf-managed-beans