# Primefaces open dialog into dialog programmatically

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I can open a dialog programmatically in primefaces like this post :

[Primefaces open closable dialog programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821590/primefaces-open-closable-dialog-programmatically)

I can open another dialog into my dialog too ! but when I want to close it with this code it won't close !

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog(null);
```

and I can't click on anything

it happen only when I open 2 dialogs into each other

**index.xhtml**

```
<p:commandButton value="Open First Dialog" process="@form" update="@form" actionListener="#{mybean.openFirstDialog}"/>
```

**mybean.java**

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class MyBean{

 public void openFirstDialog() {
        RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

        Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();

        options.put("modal", true);
        options.put("width", "850");
        options.put("contentWidth", "520");
        options.put("closable", false);
        options.put("resizable", false);

        requestContext.openDialog("/page/firstdialog", options, null);
    }

}
```

**firstdialog.xhtml**

```
<p:commandButton value="Open Second Dialog" process="@form" update="@form" actionListener="#{firstDialogBean.openSecondDialog}"/>
```

**FirstDialogBean.java**

```
@Component
@Scope("view")
public class FirstDialogBean{

public void openSecondDialog() {
        RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

        Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();

        options.put("modal", true);
        options.put("width", "850");
        options.put("contentWidth", "520");
        options.put("closable", false);
        options.put("resizable", false);

        requestContext.openDialog("/page/seconddialog", options, null);
    }

}
```

**seconddialog.xhtml**

```
<p:commandButton value="Close Second Dialog" process="@form" update="@form" actionListener="#{secondDialogBean.close}"/>
```

**secondDialogBean.java**

```
@Component
@Scope("view")
public class SecondDialogBean{
public void close() {
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog(null);
    }
}
```

actually i don't pass NULL while I'm closing dialog ! I do stuff and pass an object ! but I can't write full code here
then while I close second dialog I can get that Object in first Dialog and again do some stuff

I hope I could say what I mean

and after clicking "Close Second Dialog" it stuck !
I tried this too but no use :

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog("/page/seconddialog");
```

Comment: but if I use closable dialog it work ! I can close second dialog but I need it to be as button

Answer (score 0):

You need to name what dialog you are closing like...

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("titleEdit", options,
                null);

RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog("titleEdit");
```

See [this example](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=35809) for having two dialogs open at once and how to close them.

Comment: you mean add @Named annotation on dialog bean ? because that "titleEdit" is the return value when you close dialog and I need that to return object

Comment: Edited my answer.  No the "widgetVar" you give the dialog in the openDialog() call is the one you have to use to close it.  You example you passed it NULL you need to pass it the title of the dialog that matches what you used in the openDialog() call.

Comment: actually i don't pass NULL , I pass an ID then I get The ID from SelectEvent and use it in some cases , so I can't just change it

Comment: Please edit your post and post your full example.  In your code above you clearly pass closeDialog(null); so how am I to assume you are doing anything else than what you posted? Without all of your code how can anyone help you?